# Bug in FFI when passing CString followed by an int

Tags: windows, rust, 32-bit, ffi

My Rust test code

```
extern "C" {
fn test_int_only(n : libc::c_int);
fn test_int_and_str(s : CString , n : libc::c_int);
}

pub fn test1() { 
unsafe {
    test_int_only(0);
    test_int_only(1);
    test_int_only(2);
    test_int_only(4);
    test_int_only(-12);
    }
}


pub fn test2() { 
unsafe {
    test_int_and_str(CString::new("Foo").unwrap(),0);
    test_int_and_str(CString::new("Bar").unwrap(),1);
    test_int_and_str(CString::new("Baz").unwrap(),2);
    test_int_and_str(CString::new("Fub").unwrap(),4);
    test_int_and_str(CString::new("Bub").unwrap(),-12);
    }
}
```

My C code

```
void test_int_only(int abc){
    printf("%d\n", abc);
}

void test_int_and_str(const char* name,int abc) {
    printf("%s %d\n", name, abc);
}
```

When testing for test_int_only()

```
1
2
4
-12
```

When testing for test_int_and_str()

```
Foo 4
Bar 4
Baz 4
Fub 4
Bub 4
```

It seems that the 2nd arg is being interpreted (either in rust or c) as sizeof string, rather than the value passed from the Rust code. I'm guessing it's related to either a calling convention or null termination not working correctly. It's a C dll, with _cdecl (windows 32bit dll) calling convention. Interestingly, passing a (opaque) pointer and an int (in another test) works fine so I don't think it's a calling convention issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that the 2nd arg is being interpreted (either in rust or c) as sizeof string, rather than the value passed from the Rust code.

Correct. You are experiencing undefined behavior here.

Your C-Function has a different signature from the extern function you declared in Rust-Code. First of all, passing types that are not `#[repr(C)]` to an extern function is undefined behavior and there used to be a lint for that afaik. Second, a `CString` is not a `char*`, it is a struct with internal data. If you want to pass a `const char*`, you have to pass a `*const u8`. You can get such a pointer from a `CString` through the `into_ptr` function.

Note that `into_ptr` leaks the memory, you need to use `from_ptr` again to get a `CString` object that can get deallocated.
If you just want to lend out the `CString` object you can do something along the following lines:

```
// ensure c_str lives longer than the function call
let c_str = CString::new("Foo").unwrap();
unsafe { test_int_and_str(c_str.as_ptr(), 0); }
// let the destructor of c_str free the memory
```

Comment: Didn't get an linting error which is a shame. Though I see value in the explicitness of the FFI it's a shame because the client of my C function needs to know so much. I end up with `test_int(CString::new("Foo").unwrap().as_ptr(),0);` - quite a mouthful

Comment: you can always create a macro that does this for you and hides the boilerplate

Comment: @Ronnie, the reason `CString` exists is that Rust strings are not zero-terminated and can contain zeros inside of them. You *have* to do an allocation to go from `&str` to a proper `const char*`, and it is better be done by some standard library construct. You can always wrap your C functions in idiomatic Rust code to avoid exposing `CString`s to your clients.

Comment: @ker, I believe that `as_bytes_with_nul()` and a cast is not the intended way to get a pointer; you should use [`as_ptr()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) method which comes from `Deref<Target=CStr>`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev you are right... it looked quite bad, makes sense there's a better way. I edited the answer

Comment: @ker you mean something like `fn from_str(s: &str)`? That's because of the same reason I said above - C strings are zero-terminated while Rust strings are not. You just can't get a pointer to the beginning of `&str` and pass it to a C function as a `const char*`, there may be no zero at the end of it, and then C code will likely read outside of the bounds of the allocated memory.

Comment: maybe something could be done for `&'static str`... but that would probably need to be a plugin-macro...